# Convert my coordinate to actual JavaFx coordinate

Tags: java, math, javafx

I'm trying to build a game called [Cascadia](https://www.alderac.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Cascadia-Rules.pdf). Since every tile is a hexagon, to represent it I used a hashmap to store the point(coordinate) and the tile.

`HashMap<Point, Tile> board;`

The point follows this [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdLT.png).

Each tile is a width of 100 pixels.
example of a [tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlrqA.png).

The problem is how do I convert those points that I used in my hashmap and convert it into the actual coordinate on my scene?

I have no problem with the tiles going left or right since I can just add or subtract 100(pixels).

Comment: It depends how you have things set up. I think the way I would set this up, I wouldn’t even need to make that conversion.

Comment: you can retrieve that data  from pick result  . do you want a hint ?

Comment: It would seem that `HashMap<Tile, Point> board;` would be more useful.  Also, the points could be a field member of a tile and you would not need to maintain a map at all, the board could just be a list of tiles, and the list could be ordered by point coordinates using a comparator if needed and there is some natural ordering here.  Just some thoughts, there are many ways to implement this.

Comment: Specifically, given the size of each hexagon and the hexagon board coordinates you showed, you can easily figure out where to draw the hexagon. The only reason I can see that you’d want to go from pixel coordinates to the hexagon is if you needed to process user mouse clicks. But if you render each hexagon with a `Polygon`, you can just register mouse handlers directly with each `Polygon`, and you’d never need to do that calculation. At any rate, the answer to this depends greatly on the implementation you choose, which you haven’t shown in the question.

Comment: @James_D I can't quite figure out where to draw the hexagon :(. So let's say if I was given the point (1,0) I can easily convert that to (100,0), (2,0) -> (200,0), (-1,0) -> (-100,0)... but when it comes to points like (2,-1) how do I convert that?

Comment: Given your layout, you can figure the coordinates of hexagon (x,y+1) relative to hexagon (x,y) using basic trigonometry. As you've pointed out, hexagon (x+k,y) is just k*100 to the right of hexagon (x,y). From there it's trivial to figure out a formula for the position of hexagon (x,y).

Answer (score 3):

**Storing coordinates as field**

In this approach `Hexagon`  instances have two integers wich represent coords . Any hexagon will print x and y as stage tittle like so :

[image: hexagon javafx]

This is a single javafx app you can try

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    double HexagonRadius = 100;

    Hexagon hexagon1 = new Hexagon(1, 2, HexagonRadius, Color.CADETBLUE);

    Hexagon hexagon2 = new Hexagon(1, 0, HexagonRadius, Color.MEDIUMPURPLE);
    hexagon2.setTranslateY(hexagon1.getOffsetY() * 2);

    Hexagon hexagon3 = new Hexagon(1, 1, HexagonRadius, Color.MEDIUMSEAGREEN);
    hexagon3.setTranslateY(-hexagon1.getOffsetY() * 2);

    Hexagon hexagon4 = new Hexagon(0, 0, HexagonRadius, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
    hexagon4.setTranslateY(-hexagon1.getOffsetY());
    hexagon4.setTranslateX(hexagon1.getOffsetX());

    Hexagon hexagon5 = new Hexagon(2, 2, HexagonRadius, Color.YELLOW);
    hexagon5.setTranslateY(-hexagon1.getOffsetY());
    hexagon5.setTranslateX(-hexagon1.getOffsetX());

    Hexagon hexagon6 = new Hexagon(2, 0, HexagonRadius, Color.ORANGE);
    hexagon6.setTranslateY(hexagon1.getOffsetY());
    hexagon6.setTranslateX(-hexagon1.getOffsetX());

    Hexagon hexagon7 = new Hexagon(2, 3, HexagonRadius, Color.SKYBLUE);
    hexagon7.setTranslateY(hexagon1.getOffsetY());
    hexagon7.setTranslateX(hexagon1.getOffsetX());

    Group hexagonsGroup
            = new Group(hexagon1, hexagon2, hexagon3, hexagon4, hexagon5, hexagon6, hexagon7);

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(hexagonsGroup);

    var scene = new Scene(stackPane, 640, 480);
    scene.setFill(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public final class Hexagon extends Group {

    private Polygon polygon;
    private final double radius;
    private final double radianStep = (2 * Math.PI) / 6;

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    private final double offsetY;
    private final double offsetX;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Hexagon(int x, int y, double radius, Paint color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        makeHexagon(radius, color);
        offsetY = calculateApothem();

        offsetX = radius * 1.5;
        changeTittle();

    }

    private void makeHexagon(double radius, Paint color) {
        polygon = new Polygon();
        this.getChildren().add(polygon);
        polygon.setFill(color);
        polygon.setStroke(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        polygon.setEffect(new DropShadow(10, Color.BLACK));
        polygon.setStrokeWidth(10);
        polygon.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            double angle = radianStep * i;

            polygon.getPoints().add(Math.cos(angle) * radius / 1.1);
            polygon.getPoints().add(Math.sin(angle) * radius / 1.1);

        }
    }

    public void changeTittle() {

        polygon.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            Stage stage = (Stage) this.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setTitle("cordinate =" + x + "," + y);
        });

    }

    public double getOffsetY() {
        return offsetY;
    }

    public double getOffsetX() {
        return offsetX;
    }

    private double calculateApothem() {
        System.out.println(Math.tan(radianStep) * radius);
        return (Math.tan(radianStep) * radius) / 2;

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

}
```

Comment: Perhaps set [layout X, and Y](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty()) rather than translate. Of course, either will work.  One advantage of using the layout properties, is that the translate properties can then still be used for translate transitions if needed.